# How do I align two buttons under two different sized DIV's while keeping them responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align buttons at the bottom of two divs. They are different sizes and I can't figure it out. If I give the smaller div a min-height: 514px; it will be way too big on smaller screens.

I am using Bootstrap.

```
    <div id="front_page_body" class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="col-md-4 centered">
        <h2>Want to learn programming skills and get a better job?</h2>
        <p>More than just a hacker school, PDX Code Guild offers small class sizes with individual attention. All PDX Code Guild Programs are designed to get you the best education possible in just a few intense months! Jumpstart your career!  <br>
          <br>
          PDX Code Guild offers:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Python-based Junior Developer Training</li>
          <li>Get Technical! A Workshop for Non-technical Startup Founders</li>
          <li>Assisted Freelancing</li>
        </ul>
        <p>If you're considering upgrading your skills, we would love to hear from you! To start the conversation <a href="contact/">contact us</a>, or take the direct route and apply today!</p>
        <p class="text-center"> <a href="/apply/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Interested!</a> </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 centered">
        <h2>Events - PDX Code Guild Python Peer Mentoring Night</h2>
        <p>Come on down to PDX Code Guild for Monday Python Peer Mentoring Night. This event is free and open to the public. We invite all levels of programmers from beginner to expert. There’s something for everyone at this event! You can mentor, learn and network!</p>
        <ul>
          <li>At NedSpace on 5th
          <br/>1400 SW 5th, 3rd floor</li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-center">
        <a href="http://calagator.org/events/search?tag=PDXCodeGuild" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" target="_blank">Upcoming Events</a>
        </p>
    </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 --></div>
    </div>
```

I was going to post an image but I am not cool enough yet. The site is http://pdxcodeguild.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quick and dirty solution is to use media queries and change the code for the two breakpoints before it collapses to mobile view. Give the buttons a special class .imabutton and add a class to the container div .imadiv

```
@media screen only and (min-width: 1230px) {
  .imadiv {min-height:514px;}
  .imabutton {position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0;
}

@media screen only and (min-width: 990px) {
  .imadiv {min-height:607px;}
}
```

The drawback to this is that you will have to change those min-heights every time you add/remove content. Alternatively, you can use javascript to force the .imadiv(s) to the same height and use the same .imabutton code as above. Something like this -